# How can I install support for the Yoruba language?

Tags: language-support

I need my Ubuntu to support a language called Yoruba.

The instructions are available for Ubuntu 12.04 on the below link.
https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/language-pack-yo-base
gives the commands as

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install language-pack-yo-base
```

When I run the second command in Ubuntu 22.04, I get this error

```
E: Unable to locate package language-pack-yo-base
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 6):

It's not an error. The Yoruba langpack is currently suspended due to lack of interested contributors.

Take a look at the review of translation statistics for Yoruba in Ubuntu:
https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+lang/yo

You can see that for 22.04, few strings have been translated into Yoruba. This generally an indication that there are too few volunteer translators.

This can be undone, and the Yoruba langpack can be resurrected with some volunteer interest in translating. Gather a couple like-minded friends and contact the [Ubuntu Translation Coordinators](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-translations-coordinators) to restore the Yoruba langpack.

Comment: Thank you for that useful info. 


I fail to see the correlation though, on why Yoruba language pack would be suspended on LInux. That makes Linux less attractive to Yoruba users, when YO language packs are easily available for Windows and Mac OS. In fact, the lack of support is one reason for someone to reject Linux.


For me, I just want the ability to type Yoruba on Ubuntu. I'm not interested in switching to Yoruba language system-wide.

Comment: Edited to clarify that "support" is usually provided, in the Free Software community, by volunteers. No volunteers = No support. No volunteer translators = No language pack. Sure, other platforms do it differently...and those other platforms have a revenue stream to pay for these little features.

Comment: >>"support" is usually provided, in the Free Software community, by volunteers. No volunteers = No support<<

That is understood. I'm saying that the language pack existed at least, in Ubuntu 12.04. Does translation have to be done for every new version? By removing the language pack, the keyboard was also removed. For me, the keyboard is all I need.

Comment: @Rik - you have to "expect" that 22.04 is vastly different than 12.04. It starts with the unity desktop afaik and many programs have newer versions that contain more text that would have to be translated. Hence the people behind ubuntu didnt just include the old langpack from 12.04.

Answer (score 6):

I understand from the discussion at [user535733's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440106/301745) that you actually ask about **typing** the Yoruba language, not using it as the language for displaying menus and messages. And in that case your desire has nothing to do with language packs.

Actually a Yoruba keyboard layout is available by default. Go to Settings -> Keyboard, click the '+' button and proceed to "Other". Then enter `yoruba` in the search field and add the resulting layout.

Comment: I tried your suggestion before, but for some reason, I don't have Yoruba on the list of languages. Mine stops at Yakut.

Comment: @Rik: Hmm.. Can you please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `locale -a`

Answer (score 5):

As I said before, I just wanted to be able to type Yoruba on my keyboard.
My research turned up "Keyman for Linux".
The installation is a two-step process.

1. Install Keyman for Linux.
   https://keyman.com/linux/download
   Keyman supports hundreds of languages.
2. Install the "Yoruba" keyboard.
   https://keyman.com/go/package/download/sil_yoruba8?platform=linux&version=1.1&tier=stable

Step 2 downloaded sil_yoruba8.kmp

How to install the keyboard after the .kmp download

Click Activities,
Type: keyman,
Open: Keyman config

Click Install.
Select the sil_yoruba8.kmp file.

Once installed, it should already be added to your keyboard options.
Look at the top bar. You should see: en. Click it to switch languages.

You can even type into the same document in multiple languages. Just keep switching the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

For typing in Ubuntu 20.04, I can enable Yoruba in Settings --> Language and Region --> Input Sources --> + --> ⁞ --> Other (wait a bit) --> Yoruba (use mouse wheel to scroll to very bottom)

## Step by step

### Go to settings, choose "Language and Region" on left, select "+"

[image: 1]

### Select the "⁞" in input source dialog

[image: 2]

### Select "Other"

[image: 3]

### Select "Yoruba"

[image: 4]

Comment: "Region & Language" does not have "Input Sources". The correct sequence is **Keyboard** --> Input Sources --> + --> ⁞ --> Other (wait a bit) --> Yoruba.

Comment: @user68186 add screenshots to clarify "Input Sources" region. Found issue. I am on 20.04.

Comment: Here is the screenshot from 22.04. https://i.imgur.com/hQ7q1Rg.png